# Covariance calculation for mixture Gauss

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, matlab

This equation what I found on the wikipedia is a bit strange for me.

[image]

How I can compute in matlab?
If example the size(x) = [1000, 2](2 dimension gauss) then $size(\mu) = [1, 2]$ for each cluster.

I try with the following:

```
gaussEvaluation(i,:) = pInit(i) * mvnpdf(x,muInit(i,:), sigmaInit(i, :) * eye(d));
gaussEvaluationSum = sum(gaussEvaluation(i, :));

for j = 1 : n 
    v = (x(j, :) - muNew(i, :));
    sigmaNew(i) = sigmaNew(i) + gaussEvaluation(i,j) * (v * v');
end
sigmaNew(i) = sigmaNew(i) / gaussEvaluationSum;
```

OR

```
sub = bsxfun(@minus, x, mu(i,:));
sigma(i,:) = sum(gaussEvaluation(i,:) * (sub .* sub)) / gaussEvaluationSum;
```

Comment: I'm not a Matlab expert, but both versions of the code look like they do what they should do. It's a bit confusing that you use $i$ instead of $t+1$ and $j$ instead of $i$, but this does not matter. Presumably you have muNew calculated somewhere behind the scenes.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I calculate the new elsewhere, but I am sure that is correct. the i shows the actual cluster, the j shows the actual point, the full algorithm is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323549/custom-algorithm-for-exp-maximization